# Where is this keyword argument coming from? TypeError python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am going through a udemy python tutorial pricing project to scrape data off of a website. I am having trouble figuring out why I am getting the following error:

### Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "F:\PROGRAMMING\pycharm_projects\pricing_servicev2\alert_updater.py", line 3, in 
alerts = Alert.all()

File "F:\PROGRAMMING\pycharm_projects\pricing_servicev2\models\alert.py", line 36, in all
return [cls(**alert) for alert in alerts_from_db]

File "F:\PROGRAMMING\pycharm_projects\pricing_servicev2\models\alert.py", line 36, in 
return [cls(**alert) for alert in alerts_from_db]

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

================================================================================================

### alert.py:

```
import uuid
from typing import Dict, List
from models.item import Item
from common.database import Database


class Alert:
    def __init__(self, item_id: str, price_limit: float, _id: str = None):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.item = Item.get_by_id(item_id)
        self.price_limit = price_limit
        self.collection = "alerts"
        self._id = _id or uuid.uuid4().hex

    def json(self) -> Dict:
        return {
            "_id": self._id,
            "price_limit": self.price_limit,
            "item_id": self.item_id
        }

    def save_to_mongo(self):
        Database.insert(self.collection, self.json())

    def load_item_price(self):
        self.item.load_price()
        return self.item.price

    def notify_if_price_reached(self):
        if self.item.price < self.price_limit:
            print(f"Item {self.item} has reached a price under {self.price_limit}. Latest price: {self.item.price}.")

    @classmethod
    def all(cls) -> List:
        alerts_from_db = Database.find("alerts", {})
        return [cls(**alert) for alert in alerts_from_db]
```

====================================================================================================

### alert_updater.py

```
from models.alert import Alert

alerts = Alert.all()

for alert in alerts:
    alert.load_item_price()
    alert.notify_if_price_reached()

if not alerts:
    print("No alerts have been created. Add an item and an alert to begin!")
```

===============================================================================

### item.py

```
import requests
from typing import Dict, List
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import uuid
from common.database import Database


class Item:
    def __init__(self, url: str, tag_name: str, query: Dict, _id: str = None):
        self.url = url
        self.tag_name = tag_name
        self.query = query
        self.price = None
        self.collection = "items"
        self._id = _id or uuid.uuid4().hex

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Item {self.url}>"

    def load_price(self) -> float:
        response = requests.get(self.url)
        content = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
        element = soup.find(self.tag_name, self.query)
        string_price = element.text.strip()

        pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+,?\d*\.\d\d)")
        match = pattern.search(string_price)
        found_price = match.group(1)
        without_commas = found_price.replace(",", "")
        self.price = float(without_commas)
        return self.price

    def json(self) -> Dict:
        return {
            "_id": self._id,
            "url": self.url,
            "tag_name": self.tag_name,
            "query": self.query
        }

    def save_to_mongo(self):
        Database.insert(self.collection, self.json())

    @classmethod
    def get_by_id(cls, _id):
        item_json = Database.find_one("items", {"_id": _id})
        return cls(**item_json)

    @classmethod
    def all(cls) -> List:
        items_from_db = Database.find("items", {})
        return [cls(**item) for item in items_from_db]
```

=================================================================

Why do I have a keyword argument id being created?? Please help and thank you all for your contributions:)

Comment: Have you inspected the value of the `alerts_from_db` variable after calling `alerts_from_db = Database.find("alerts", {})`? You're using the results of that query as keyword arguments.

Comment: @larsks After running the debugger on pycharm and inspecting the above variable, I found out that something was wrong with my database. I think when I initially created data in my database I accidentally added id... Thanks for your help!